# Android: Problems with retrofit2 and multipart

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I am experiencing issues when i try to upload files to my backend. The files that I am trying to upload are images. In the backend I have the next code to take it:

```
@Context private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest hsr;    
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void buildTree() {
        String contextName=hsr.getContextPath().substring(1);
        System.out.println("contextName: "+contextName);
        String folderNames[]={"img"};
        
        FileUtils.generateFolderTree(contextName, folderNames);
    }
    @Path("/uploadFile")
    @POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
        System.out.println("uploadFile: "+hsr.getRemoteAddr());
        Response httpResponse;
        if(SecUtils.checkAuthorization(hsr, em, "student")) {
            httpResponse=FileUtils.uploadFile(input);//9S: Recoger el fichero recibido como contenido multipart, escribirlo en la ubicación por defecto y crear el httpResponse correspondiente 
        }
        else {
            httpResponse=Response.status(401).entity("WRONG CREDENTIALS").build();
        }
        return httpResponse;        
    }
```

As you can see it consumes data of type multipart/form-data, I try to upload it with the next android java functions:

API CALL retrofit2

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("uploadFile")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadSolution(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

And I use it by the next way:

```
 public void uploadSolution(InputStream is, String name) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),data);
        MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", name, file);
        Response<ResponseBody> response=api.uploadSolution( part).execute();
        Log.d("foto", Integer.toString(response.code()));
    }
```

As you can see I am tetsing the response getting the response code and I get the 500 code.

Does anybody know if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks for support!

Comment: HTTP 500 is server-side. There's `SecUtils.checkAuthorization` but no client authorization.

Comment: As you can see, I use an api object which implements the API interface that contains the API calls, that interface is implemented with the authorization parameters previously. Thanks but that is not the problem.